# Getting a specific character in Java given two parameters

Tags: java, matrix, encryption

> I'm looking to find an uppercase letter associated with a given row and column of lower case letters in a java program.
> [image]

> My specific question is how do you find the character at two indexes? I'm thinking of something like

UPPERCASE_LETTERS.indexOf.charAt(row, column);

> But I know that's incorrect. Any suggestions? Thanks y'all

Comment: As I understood, you want to find cells that match with a given row and column, right?

Comment: Yes, I do. That is a much better way to phrase my question, thank you.

Comment: So, when the cell will match with the row and column? For example, for the row 'a' and column 'b', the value is 'B'. Is it matches?

Comment: Yes, and 't' and 'g' would result in Z. The idea is that you use the row as a key, and the column as a message, and the resulting uppercase letter would represent the code encrypted

Comment: I am confused a bit. Do you want to pass (t, g) to a function or anything else and get Z ?

Comment: No, 't' and 'g' would always result in Z, because in this particular cipher, the Vigenere Cipher, there is a pattern of symmetry. If you were to randomize the inner upper letters then 't' as a row and 'g' column would result in something different than 't' as a column and 'g' as a row.

Comment: [Burrows-Wheeler transform](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Burrows%E2%80%93Wheeler_transform)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that we have a two-dimensional array named `UPPERCASE_LETTERS`. You achieve your goal using the code as follow:

```
String charAt(char key, char message) {
    int row = key - 'a';
    int column = message - 'a';

    return UPPERCASE_LETTERS[row][column];
}
```

Comment: @Laura accept the correct answer, if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You have rotated arrays of the english alphabet. You don't even need to declare the table shown in your example. You need to only add the column index to the row (which is column value - 97) and substract 26 if it is greater than `z`:

```
static char getResult(char row, char column){
    char c = (char)(row + column - 97);
    if(c > 'z') c = (char) (c - 26);
    return Character.toUpperCase(c);
}
```